# C# access database issue

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;       
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Desktop\Db11.accdb";
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Table1 (Customer,Description,Color,Status,)VALUES('" + tBox3.Text + "','" + tBox1.Text + "','" + tBox12.Text + "','" + cBox2.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recrod Succefully Created");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { MessageBox.Show("error " + ex); }


}
```

now my data base has 
other fields the prime key is ID and it has things like sqft rons peices so on. i dont need to fill them all in do i ? i get an error every time 
syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: I'd suggest not using a CommandText - it's not clean, more security issues,etc - and using a stored procedure instead. Test the stored procedure from the DB first to make sure that end works. Then add the required code to the c# end to call the stored procedure.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your SQL is misspelled. Correct example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;       
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Desktop\Db11.accdb";
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Table1 (Customer,Description,Color,Status) VALUES('" + tBox3.Text + "','" + tBox1.Text + "','" + tBox12.Text + "','" + cBox2.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recrod Succefully Created");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("error " + ex); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to provide values of all the columns in a `INSERT` statement.
If the fields are set auto increment or allowing `NULL` values, you can omit those fields.
In your case, I think you should set primary key `ID` as auto increment with other fields allowing `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ',' after the "Status"-field. You shouldn't append values directly to the command, but rather use parametrized values. Also you can use "using" -statements to automatically close and dispose both the connection and command. Here's little code to help you out:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Desktop\Db11.accdb"))
{
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"
        INSERT INTO 
            Table1(Customer,Description,Color,Status)
            VALUES(@Customer,@Description,@Color,@Status)
    ", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Customer", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = tBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Description", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = tBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Color", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = tBox12.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Status", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = cBox2.Text;

        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recrod Succefully Created");
    }
}
```